# Javascript getChannelData some out of bounds

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

When I do audioBuffer.getChannelData I'm expecting a Float32Array where all the elements are between -1 and 1. But for some files some elements are as high as 1.018

According to web docs it "needs to be in [-1.0; 1.0]" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer/getChannelData

This breaks my compression algorithm and I'm wondering why this happens and if it's safe to clamp all the elements between -1 and 1. Or will it be much more out of bounds for some audio files?

Here's an example with a mp3 that I didn't create.
http://curtastic.com/testdecode.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
            var gaudiocontext = new AudioContext()

            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
            ajax.open("GET", 'nightmare.mp3', true)
            ajax.responseType = "arraybuffer"
            ajax.onload = function()
            {
                gaudiocontext.decodeAudioData(
                    ajax.response,
                    function(buffer)
                    {
                        console.log(buffer)
                        var a = buffer.getChannelData(0)
                        for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                        {
                            var v = a[i]
                            if(v > 1 || v < -1)
                            {
                                document.write(i+": "+v+"<br>")
                                console.log(i, v)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
            ajax.send()

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result on my chrome and firefox

```
275074: -1.0023564100265503
275298: 1.0011343955993652
390369: -1.0034352540969849
406446: 1.0043694972991943
406966: 1.001240611076355
464391: -1.0022114515304565
473795: -1.0013331174850464
473796: -1.0011906623840332
489287: 1.0000232458114624
489288: 1.0015380382537842
505246: 1.0035203695297241
538104: 1.0000414848327637
538105: 1.0010102987289429
538654: 1.0025116205215454
669162: 1.0007333755493164
669163: 1.0028942823410034
768849: -1.0007946491241455
777504: -1.007991909980774
801369: 1.008617639541626
869400: 1.0121995210647583
870947: 1.0112541913986206
1040100: 1.0010311603546143
1040104: 1.0021687746047974
1065010: -1.0000600814819336
1067414: -1.0003679990768433
1133228: -1.002819299697876
1133230: -1.0011301040649414
1195266: 1.0021108388900757
1195496: -1.000971794128418
1262475: -1.0009863376617432
1262744: 1.001728892326355
1262854: 1.005579948425293
1266068: -1.0022647380828857
1270317: -1.0008227825164795
1270322: -1.0015367269515991
1279046: -1.0031969547271729
1279070: -1.0004109144210815
1279080: -1.0048373937606812
1279233: 1.0006334781646729
1281418: -1.0135412216186523
1283600: -1.010787010192871
1285748: 1.0044399499893188
1288197: 1.0003455877304077
1294381: 1.0324506759643555
1294399: 1.0016738176345825
1295138: 1.0029387474060059
1295170: 1.0082039833068848
1295417: -1.0360995531082153
1295447: -1.0007649660110474
1295448: -1.0020323991775513
1295451: -1.0009381771087646
1295488: -1.0024218559265137
1295511: -1.0012314319610596
1296859: 1.0096046924591064
1299037: 1.0260592699050903
1299277: 1.005500078201294
1299449: -1.0101513862609863
1299473: -1.0100860595703125
1299475: -1.004179835319519
1301302: -1.0012340545654297
1302846: -1.0252602100372314
1303408: 1.0005576610565186
1303409: 1.0025590658187866
1303915: 1.009533405303955
1304102: -1.0001871585845947
1304307: -1.0025089979171753
1304586: 1.0183976888656616
1304694: 1.0019795894622803
1305746: 1.018847107887268
1306249: 1.0039864778518677
1306252: 1.001012921333313
1306272: 1.0042804479599
1306431: -1.0356990098953247
1306439: -1.0191256999969482
1307601: -1.0156844854354858
1310684: -1.0025532245635986
1311639: 1.020194172859192
1312099: 1.00885009765625
1312975: -1.0107345581054688
1313035: -1.0103509426116943
1313209: 1.0090372562408447
1313229: 1.014164686203003
1313473: -1.0009111166000366
1314270: -1.0130990743637085
1314990: -1.0097541809082031
1314995: -1.0220547914505005
1315724: -1.0092028379440308
1317747: -1.0046861171722412
1318425: -1.00058913230896
1318898: -1.0501095056533813
1319753: -1.0026195049285889
1319967: 1.001883864402771
1320248: -1.0159223079681396
```

Comment: For that sample, nothing but the buffer object is logged in my browsers (Firefox and Chromium on Linux). What platform/browsers are you using?

Comment: Oh wow both my Chrome and my Firefox must decode differently than yours. Must be just a slight variation then

Comment: Windows 10 with Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The numbers are slightly different on my Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 (64-bit), but about the same amount and variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce it on Firefox for Windows. Not sure why you might be getting these out-of-range values, but the [spec says](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audio-sample-values)

> The range of all audio signals at a destination node of any audio
>   graph is nominally [-1, 1]. The audio rendition of signal values
>   outside this range, or of the values NaN, positive infinity or
>   negative infinity, is undefined by this specification.

Undefined means you can do anything you like in this case. Clamping seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Just as a side-note: you *do* want those values to go out of range if you have a chain of processing so that you preserve the dynamic range until the very end (although there should rarely be need for a range to go outside; you want to work at a sweet.spot level depending on what processing is needed). Clamping is one way, but I would recommend instead using a limiter, AKA a fast (attack) [compressor node](https://devdocs.io/dom/dynamicscompressornode) at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that the data in an `AudioBuffer` must be in the range [-1,1].  However, the data that eventually goes to the output device should be in that range otherwise you may get unwanted distortion. (What happens depends on the browser, but presumably most will just clamp to that range.)

Since you're getting the data from a file, I would recommend simply applying a scale factor to the data.  Say, multiply everything by .99.  Or divide everything by the max value you see.

Clipping can cause distortion, although this probably won't matter in the example you have. Scaling won't distort but you will lose the very very quiet parts of the signal.